# Fetch individual item from json in a table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I have a MySQL table with a ton of users, each user have a **row** (*"details"*)

Data example of a user:

> ["D11","E20","E70","E50","D50","G32"]

Each user could have more or none data.

Currently I fetch this data per user with a simple

```
while ($row = pg_fetch_array($resultado)) {
    $details = $row["details"];
}
```

What I want is to be able to select the 1, 2, 3 and 4 item from this "array" or "json" not sure what it is or how to format it correctly.

I wanna be able to just save this first item in a custom var, like

```
MainDetail = "D11";
```

I tried with json encode, serialize, without luck :/

Comment: Have you tried `$mainDetail = $row["details"][0]`?

Comment: your row `details` have serialized data or json data in it?

Comment: Please show more of your codes. I think you use ajax code and some php function to send json encode to ajax. Need to see to help.

Comment: The way I posted, it's how it is. In a varchar type of data.

Comment: what data is saved? `["D11","E20","E70","E50","D50","G32"]`->exactly this one?

Comment: I tried with  $mainDetail = $row["details"][0], it will only echo ->  " [ "

Comment: Exactly! That's how data is formatted. But each user could have other values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you have saved string inside column and you think that either it's an array or serialize/json data.

Please do like below:-

```
while ($row = pg_fetch_array($resultado)) {
    echo $details = str_replace(array('[','"'),'',explode(",",$row["details"])[0]);
}
```

Comment: I love you dude! Worked great!

Comment: @BWayne  glad to help you. But try to create separate table for this column and save every data with single-single row based on `user_id`. This called normalization and that the correct way. OR atleast save data in serialized format in this particular column,not in string format. data-handling will become easy